# Are there any ways to increase your chances of capturing a Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've come across a wild Pokemon with a red circle around it and it broke out of the Pokeball rather quickly. Is there something I can do next time to increase my chances of capturing it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at this article [Pokemon GO: 9 Essential Tips, Tricks & Answers To Your Questions](http://gameranx.com/features/id/63505/article/pokemon-go-essential-tips-tricks-answers-to-your-questions/)

**How to capture Pokemon**

> 1. Use the Item bag to toss Pokeballs or use items (like Razz berries) to make capturing a Pokemon easier. Improved Pokeballs such as Great Balls, Ultra Balls or Master Balls will also improve your chances.
> 2. The targeting circle tells you how tough the capture will be. A green circle is best, following by a yellow, orange, and red circle. Yellow circles, in our experience, are a pretty tough capture — orange and red? Wait until you’ve got the right items to make capturing easier.
> 3. Wait until the targeting circle is at its smallest before flinging a Pokeball. The smaller the circle, the better your chances of capturing will be.

Comment: One thing that confused me - it's not just when the colored targeting circle is smallest - it's the smaller it is such that you still hit inside the targeting circle. If the targeting circle is small but you hit outside of it, there's no bonus.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as you progress further into the game you will find [Berries](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221957668-Available-items-and-your-Bag) which will make it easier for you to catch Pokémon during encounters.