# What are all the factors which affect catch chance?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a comprehensive list of factors that alter the catch chance in Pokemon Go?

For example [I know about](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272577/125786) Razz Berry's, Great Ball's and Ultra Ball's increase the capture chance, and I know tapping the screen *does not*. What else is there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Factors that affect catch rate:

- Pokemon species
- Pokemon level - [Details](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4v52le/base_capture_rate/)
- Type of Pokeball used

  - [image] Normal
  - [image] Great
  - [image] Ultra
  - [image] Master (100%)
- [image] Razz Berry used or not
- Curve ball bonus - [Details](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/277494/125786)
- Nice / Great / Excellent throw bonus'

Estimated Multipliers for items:

- Razz Berry: 1.5x
- Golden Razz Berry: 2.5x
- Curve Ball: 1.2x
- Nice Throw: 1x
- Great Throw: 1.3x
- Excellent Throw: 1.5x

Estimated Chance % for capture circle:

- Green: ~66-100%
- Yellow: ~36-65%
- Orange: ~26-35%
- Red: ~0-25%

### Factors that don't affect catch rate:

- Trainer level
- Number of captures
- Pokémon's mood
- Number of attempts
- Speed of travel
- Time of day or weather
- Tapping the screen rapidly

[**Source**](http://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/catch-mechanics)

Comment: [For pokemon Level](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4v52le/base_capture_rate/) some details

Comment: Your "curve ball bonus details" seem to be about XP gained, not catch rate.

Comment: @Rawling Yeah my intention was to show it's half broken and if the bonus isn't awarded I doubt the catch chance is increased

Comment: Also, the size of the inner circle - [source](https://imgur.com/gallery/PPvuO)

Comment: I wonder why oddish was singled out as a 48% chance instead of 40% like all the other similar pokemon.
Also was unaware curve ball hate affect on catch rate.

Comment: A recent study by Gamepress puts the curved throw bonus at 1.7x. See the article on Grand Unified Catch Theory here: https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/guct-curveballs

Comment: Nice list! 2 improvements needed tho: Type Medals (Bronze/Silver/Gold for Ice, Fire, Water, etc) also improve catch rate by 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3; and accuracy bonus (Nice/Great/Excellent) is actually linear, depending on inner circle radius, ranging from 1.0 to 2.0

Comment: @MestreLion Feel free to edit!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what @Insane has said, each unique species of Pokemon has a unique **base capture rate**.

Keep in mind that the following information has been extracted from the Pokemon Go source code, and while its accuracy may seem feasible and reasonable, **it is not yet official.** That being said, this is what most people seem to believe at this point...

The following a list of the base capture rate for each of the 151 Pokemon in Pokemon Go ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vs70r/analysis_on_catch_rates_and_encounters/)):

- **Base Capture Rate**: List of Pokemon
- **56%**: Magikarp
- **48%**: Oddish
- **40%**: Caterpie, Weedle, Pidgey, Rattata, Spearow, Ekans, Sandshrew, Nidoran (male), Nidoran (female), Jigglypuff, Zubat, Venonat, Diglett, Meowth, Psyduck, Mankey, Poliwag, Abra, Machop, Bellsprout, Tentacool, Geodude, Slowpoke, Magnemite, Doduo, Seel, Grimer, Shellder, Drowzee, Krabby, Voltorb, Exeggcute, Koffing, Rhyhorn, Horsea, Goldeen, Staryu
- **32%**: Paras, Ponyta, Gastly, Cubone, Tangela, Eevee, Porygon, Omanyte, Kabuto, Dratini
- **24%**: Clefairy, Vulpix, Growlithe, Farfetch'd, Mr. Mime, Scyther, Jynx, Electabuzz, Magmar, Pinsir, Tauros, Gloom
- **20%**: Metapod, Kakuna, Pidgeotto, Nidorina, Nidorino, Poliwhirl, Kadabra, Machoke, Weepinbell, Graveler
- **16%**: Bulbasaur, Charmander, Squirtle, Pikachu, Hitmonlee, Hitmonchan, Lickitung, Chansey, Lapras, Ditto, Aerodactyl, Snorlax, Kangaskhan, Onix, Raticate, Fearow, Arbok, Sandslash, Wigglytuff, Golbat, Parasect, Venomoth, Dugtrio, Persian, Golduck, Primeape, Tentacruel, Slowbro, Magneton, Dodrio, Dewgong, Muk, Cloyster, Haunter, Hypno, Kingler, Electrode, Exeggutor, Weezing, Rhydon, Seadra, Seaking, Starmie
- **12%**: Rapidash, Marowak, Vaporeon, Jolteon, Flareon, Omastar, Kabutops, Vileplume
- **10%**: Butterfree, Beedrill, Pidgeot, Nidoqueen, Nidoking, Poliwrath, Alakazam, Machamp, Victreebel, Golem
- **8%**: Ivysaur, Charmeleon, Wartortle, Raichu, Clefable, Ninetales, Arcanine, Gyarados, Dragonair, Gengar
- **4%**: Venusaur, Charizard, Blastoise, Dragonite
- **2%**: Articuno, Lugia
- **0%**: Zapdos, Moltres, Mewtwo, Mew

Keep in mind that **base capture rate** means the probability or likelihood that you will catch a Pokemon with a PokeBall, with no throw bonus, curveball, Razz Berry, or any other feature that increases or decreases your likelihood. You can see other answers for a full list of other factors that affect catch rate.

From the above statistics, you can see that there are **five** Pokemon that are currently not catchable (with a base capture rate of 0%), including **Articuno, Zapdos, Moltres, Mewtwo, and Mew**. There is speculation that these Pokemon will be "given away" at Niantic events. It is also interesting to note that the ever mysterious **Ditto** has a base catch rate of **16%**, so if anyone can find it, it's not uncatchable.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwMgYFTd_qc) is a helpful video that essentially summarizes all of the above information in a visual, easy to understand fashion.