# What are all the factors which affect escape chance?

Tags: pokemon-go

According to the question "[What are all the factors which affect catch chance?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281186/what-are-all-the-factors-which-affect-catch-chance)" I would like to know what influences a Pokémon to escape.

Example: I do not know if this is a subjective cognition, but I think that Abra has a much higher escape rate than other Pokémon (the same like in the [Pokemon Series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-series)).

Proof:

[image: abra-pokedex]

- Seen: 13 Times
- Caught: Only 7 Times ( where 3 are from eggs)

So the bilance would be 10-4 without eggs, what would be a catch rate of less than 50% (no statistical significance of course).

What are other factors except the Pokémon itself?

Comment: For factors other than the Pokemon itself, you can find answers in the question you linked. I'm tempted to flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: @ThePickleTickler The linked question is for catch changes, this is for escape changes.

Comment: This is true, but the all other factors _other_ than the Pokemon itself are linked in that other question, maybe delete the last question on your post - "What are other factors except the Pokemon itself?", because that can be found at the linked question. The only factor that affects escape (other than base capture rate) is flee rate, which is mentioned in the below answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like lois6b pointed out the chance to run off is determined by the Pokémon species. The chance to actually capture it is different, though.

---

If you hit it with a ball you have a specified chance to capture it:

`BaseCaptureRate: 0.4` (*) - modified by [these](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281186/what-are-all-the-factors-which-affect-catch-chance?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This will determine the chance to actually capture it.

---

If it gets out you get another dice roll:

`BaseFleeRate: 0.99` (*) - modified by level (*based on experience*)

This determines the chance of the Pokémon to run away. So Abra has a 1% chance to stay.

The only exception is a soft ban: This will override the `BaseCaptureRate`with `0` and the `BaseFleeRate` with `1`. So every Pokémon runs off with no chance to capture it.

(*) = Based on *Abra*

Answer (score 3):

As you can see here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf#file-game_master_v0_1-protobuf-L8600
there is a variable in the pokemon that indicates that.

> ```
> TemplateId: "V0001_POKEMON_BULBASAUR"  
>   Pokemon {  
>     UniqueId: V0001_POKEMON_BULBASAUR  
>     }
>     Encounter {
>       BaseCaptureRate: 0.16  
>       BaseFleeRate: 0.1  
>       JumpTimeS: 1.15  
>       AttackTimerS: 29  
>     }
> ```

Comment: The question is about other factors than the Pokémon itself, like level.

Comment: While dly is true, I would still want to know if the BaseFleeRate in your example of `0.1` would mean that for every thrown ball there is a chance of 1/10 that it escapes?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 for every ball it manages to escape from it'll have that chance to run off. The answer shows bulbasaur, though. Abra actually has `BaseFleeRate: 0.99`.. 1% to stay

Comment: So the 4 Abras out of 10 from my example would be a very good catch rate. Correct?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 that's a different thing. Capturing a Pokémon is based on its `BaseCaptureRate: 0.4` which determines the chance to stay in the ball (modified by ball type, throw effects, berry, etc..). In that case 4/10 is right on the spot.

Answer (score -1):

Great question! I've been thinking a lot about the probabilities involved in catching Pokemon. I have observed that "curveballs" and balls thrown with any kind of spin have a higher catch rate. Throwing like this is harder but if you can catch the pokemon, it is much more likely to stay than just lobbing the ball at them. I don't have any numbers backing this up but it would be great if someone does.

Comment: [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281186/what-are-all-the-factors-which-affect-catch-chance?noredirect=1&lq=1) are some numbers.