# Are the colored circles affected by catch bonuses?

Tags: pokemon-go

The colored circle you see when catching Pokemon changes if different ball types are used, but doesn't change when you use a razzberry. So there doesn't seem to be consistency whether it changes based on anything besides Pokemon level, but has anyone determined whether the catch bonus changes the color at all?

Comment: It's actually the other way around

Comment: What's the other way around?

Comment: As far as I know, it changes with Razz Berry. The change is just much smaller than when you change Balls, so it's not really noticeable.

Comment: @scenia pretty sure razzberry and Greatball have the same catch boost (50%), but berries change the color far less noticeably than Greatballs, if at all

Answer (score 3):

This can help you, it calculates the catch chance with color circles and on the bottom of the page explains you a little about how they do the calc.

https://pokeassistant.com/catchchance

Extra info from link [13/10/2016]:

> This tool allows trainers to view catch chances of different Pokemon
>   based on the ball they use and the colour of the ring they observe
>   in-game.
>
> The colour of the rings in this tool match exactly the colours in game
>   thanks to some stunning research by u/dondon151 (reddit user).
>
> Ring size calculation is still tentative but accurate to a reasonably
>   large sample size thanks to a lot of work by u/RhyniD (reddit user).
>
> The science on catch chance isn't 100% complete, but for what we know
>   right now, this tool is accurate:
>
> Final Chance = 1 - (( 1 - Level Chance) ^ BallMulti) ^ SizeMulti
>
> where:
>
> Level Chance = 50% / CPMulti(Level) * Base Species Chance
>
> The SizeMulti increase from 1 to 2 as the coloured ring's size
>   decreases relative to the grey ring.
>
> The BallMulti increases from 1 -> 1.5 -> 2 as the trainer uses better
>   balls.
>
> There is no evidence yet that Berries, "Nice Throws" or curve balls
>   affect catch chance.

Info extracted from **SysDragon**'s link:

https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/catch-mechanics

The research add information about 'Great, Nice & Excellents shots' multipliers and Berries, not included on pokeassistant.

[image: Table from second link]

Comment: Fist: You should include the relevant info of the link in your answer just in case the link changes or stops working

Comment: Second: The information on the guide is incorrect (outdated). Great, Nice & Excellents shots give a boost on your capture chances.

Comment: ok thanks, any demonstration over there about the 'Great, Nice & Excellents shots' boost? @SysDragon

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/281187/43105